# Can I use a PowerShell module without installing it?

Tags: powershell

It's my first topic here!

I'm creating a script that will be stored on a network share and executed automatically by the logon of simple AD users. So, no permission to install anything and the script had to run on plenty of PCs so I can't install the module manually on each PC.

The module : https://github.com/lipkau/PsIni

Even if my code will reach 1000+ lines, is it possible to put the few functions of PsIni into my ps1 script ? Or maybe a simpler way to include it ?

Thanks!

Comment: Running a logon script with 1k loc seems excessive. What, exactly, you are trying to do? Maybe there is simpler a way.

Comment: Depending on what you try to do, it is likely you only want to be able to read and parse an ini file, so in that case you could simply incorporate the `Get-IniContent` function from that module in your own code and don't need the rest ?

Comment: The script will have to gather informations from the registry (done) then generate an ini file and save it on the network share, but the function doesn't work if PsIni isn't installed. And even with MS documentation, I don't know how to incorporate the functions I want into my script without installing the module via the "Install-Module PsIni" command

Comment: I would rather search for another solution to get the values and store them as .ini file. Importing a whole module seems like an overkill to me.

Comment: Me too, but PowerShell doesn't support ini editing natively. If there's a better solution than this module to simply put my variables into a file, I would love to know it. Another way : writing the ini syntax manually in the script

Comment: An ini file is just a text file storing `name = value` pairs each on a separate line, grouped in different sections (`[SectionName]`). Show us how you gather information from the registry. It shouldn't be too hard to manually construct an ini from the data.

Answer (score 0):

You could always run `Import-Module PSIni -Function Get-IniContent`
this will import only the Get-IniContent function. You will however still need the entire module to be present.